# Left Joining with a subselect - right table columns not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, aggregate-functions, subquery

I am working on a concert promoter's website and I have to retrieve the first, last and nearest future date for shows on each tour. I am attempting to do this with the following query:

```
SELECT tour.*, min(date) AS `startdate`, max(date) AS finaldate
  FROM tour, tour_date
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tour_id, min(date) AS nextdate
      FROM tour_date 
      WHERE date>=CURDATE()
      GROUP BY tour_id
  ) AS ndtable
    ON ndtable.tour_id=tour_date.tour_id
  WHERE tour.id=tour_date.tour_id
  GROUP BY tour_date.tour_id
  ORDER BY nextdate
```

I am getting the left table results but the "nextdate" column is not showing.

---

*EDIT: I forgot to mention that this query is only relevant for tours with shows in the future, so I was able to rearrange it like this:*

```
SELECT tour.*, MIN(td.date) AS startdate, MAX(td.date) AS lastdate, MIN(ntd.date) AS nextdate
FROM tour
JOIN tour_date AS td
  ON tour.id=td.tour_id
JOIN tour_date AS ntd
  ON tour.id=ntd.tour_id
WHERE ntd.date>CURDATE()
GROUP BY td.tour_id
ORDER BY nextdate
```

*which I think is a lot neater and efficient :)*

Comment: How about including it into your SELECT list?

Comment: Yikes. Thanks a lot. Been working for a while now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tour.*, min(date) AS `startdate`, max(date) AS finaldate, ndtable.nextdate
  FROM tour, tour_date
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tour_id, min(date) AS nextdate
      FROM tour_date 
      WHERE date>=CURDATE()
      GROUP BY tour_id
  ) AS ndtable
    ON ndtable.tour_id=tour_date.tour_id
  WHERE tour.id=tour_date.tour_id
  GROUP BY tour_date.tour_id, ndtable.nextdate
  ORDER BY nextdate
```

Comment: the OP wants `ndtable.nextdate`, I think

Comment: It's 2014 A.D. Time to ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead, and relocate the join predicates to the `ON` clause, rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm not sure what you mean by that, I haven't read up much on modern syntax since school (and I suppose I was taught the old one).

Comment: In the `FROM` clause, the tables are listed separated by commas. This the old-school syntax (i.e. pre-1992 SQL standard)... The newer join syntax replaces the comma with the keyword `JOIN`. The older syntax is sometimes referred to as "implicit" join syntax. The query in this answer mixes implicit join syntax with explicit join syntax; there is simply no good reason to do this. (On the second line of the query `FROM a,b`, the comma should be replaced... should be `FROM a JOIN b`. With this syntax, it's also possible to add an `ON` clause, and relocate predicates (conditions) from the WHERE cl

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN c ON c.col = b.col` (in the query in this answer) is an example of the newer syntax. This same pattern can be applied to the first two tables in the FROM clause, e.g. **`FROM a JOIN b ON b.col = a.col`**

Comment: Alright, I'll have that in mind for the future, thanks :) I've edited my previous edit to reflect this syntax.